# PDO fetchAll Results returns only one record issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner-join, fetchall

I have developed the following script in my localhost (using wamp 2.2, apache 2.2.1 windows, php 5.3.9, mysql 5.5.20). When I upload the script to the production server (apache 2.2.29 unix, php 5.3.29, mysql 5.5.42)

I noticed that the php+pdo script did not return all the fetched rows in the same way that the same script does in my local server.

If I try to add an "order by" sql instance, it works well on local but in production server the resulted fetched row is always the same.

Also tryed to change my INNER JOIN table order as well with same result.
Any clues? Maybe a wrong INNER JOIN

### php + pdo:

```
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydbname;charset=utf8';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

function Contents($id) {    
    global $pdo;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT historia.id AS idhistoria, pub_us.comic, pub_us.id FROM historia INNER JOIN pub_us ON pub_us.historia = historia.id WHERE pub_us.comic = :id ORDER BY orden');
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt = null;
    return $data;
}

$comicid = "fantasticfour/1/001";

$data = Contents($comicid);

foreach($data as $row) { 

    echo $row['idhistoria'];
    echo " - ";
    echo $row['comic'];
    echo " - ";
    echo $row['id'];

}
```

---

Table Structure:

```
Table structure for historia: id(text, primary key)
Table structure for pub_us: id(int,auto increment, primary key), comic(text), historia(text, related to table historia.id)
```

---

Data retrieved:

```
Results in local wamp:
|| idhistoria      || comic               || id    ||
|| fantfour-1-001b || fantasticfour/1/001 || 25356 ||
|| fantfour-1-001  || fantasticfour/1/001 || 16449 ||
|| fantfour-1-001a || fantasticfour/1/001 || 3772  ||

Results in server :
|| idhistoria      || comic               || id   ||
|| fantfour-1-001a || fantasticfour/1/001 || 3772 ||
```

Comment: That looks ok to me. Are you sure your db's are in sync? maybe var_dump $data to check if the query is executed properly

Comment: Yes, db are in sync. I used server's phpmyadmin to check the results with a simple "select * from pub_es where pub_us.comic = "fantasticfour/1/001" and I saw the three results matched. Next I try the above sql query in the same phpmyadmin and it gives me only one result. On the way: it is NOT an april's fools :/

Comment: Check database collation, characterset, same for your table and character set for connection. All this influence the kind of sorting the db does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rmertins clue, i solved the problem.

Table "historia" was with INNODB engine and table "pub_us" was with MyISAM, so differences between engines results in only one row.

Solved this changing engines to same (INNODB in this case)

Thanks for the comments and clues, I expect this helps somebody else!